# Trying to invoke method on child properties

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

In my C# application I will at times handle objects that inherit from my class `BaseDomainModel` which has a method `public virtual void ValidateModel()`. For my example, I'm getting an instance of a `CompanyUser` object which has at least one property of a type inheriting from `BaseDomainModel`.

I would like to walk through these properties and invoke the `ValidateModel()` method on those properties.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var validatableProperties = testCompanyUser.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseDomainModel));
foreach (var thisProperty in validatableProperties)
{
    var m = thisProperty.PropertyType.GetMethod("ValidateModel", Type.EmptyTypes);
    m.Invoke(thisProperty.GetValue(testCompanyUser), null);
}
```

I'm currently getting this message:

> Non-static method requires a target.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `thisProperty.GetValue(testCompanyUser)` can return `null` ( because of reference type held ) and you're not checking it.

Second one is that you're not setting `BindingFlags` in your requests for properties and methods.

Try something like this :

```
foreach(var property in testCompanyUser.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseDomainModel)))
{
    var method = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("ValidateModel", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object propValue = property.GetValue(testCompanyUser);
    if(method != null && propValue != null)
    {
        m.Invoke(propValue, null);
    }
```

As [@Phil Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746674/phil-cooper) mentioned. You can read [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) page to get more details about when `Exception` is thrown

Comment: To back this up, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) details the usage of Invoke and in particular, the conditions under which `TargetException` will be thrown.